# How to get 2nd variable of the string separated by dots?

Tags: php, substr

I have categories ({PHP.c}) that have their codes - for example
guide.cu OR guide.us OR story.cu etc and

With this function I can get the root category

```
function get_root_cat($code)
{
        return mb_substr($structure['page'][$code]['path'], 0, mb_strpos($structure['page'][$code]['path'], '.'));
}
```

So with {PHP.c|get_root_cat($this)} I can get 'guide' or 'story' etc.

But now structure gets more complicated and {PHP.c} looks like guide.cu.one, guide.cu.two or story.us.three

I need to find this: guide.**cu**.one or story.**us**.three

Comment: You might be overcomplicating this. Have a look at the PHP [string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), specifically [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
return explode(".", $structure['page'][$code]['path'])[1];
```

More info here: https://php.net/explode